# How to send/receive soap object with objective-c for ipad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, ipad, soap

I have been trying to write a objective-c application for ipad to send/receive soap web service. I have written a code but it gives an error. the webservice is working online.

here is my code,

```
-(IBAction)invokeService
{

    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                    "<soap:Body>\n"
                    "<GetUserList xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />\n"
                    "</soap:Body>\n"
                    "</soap:Envelope>\n"];


    NSLog(@"The request format is %@",soapFormat);

    NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://servicing2.rotanet.com/service1.asmx"];

    NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"GetUserList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (connect) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        startActivityIndicator;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No Connection established");
    }
}
```

I get this error message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault>  <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:  Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: GetUserList.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)  </faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am author of WSClient++ and it is a commercial product.

http://wsclient.neurospeech.com

Creating simple SOAP requests are easy, however when you have complex graph of objects, dealing with Dictionaries and raw XML can be time consuming, WSClient++ generates Objective C source code for SOAP proxy with each complex type. You just make a single method call to retrieve results.