# socket programming in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sockets

I have an app that uses socket

In my application , i am trying to establish socket connection and after connecting socket i need to send soap request to server.i'm having  problem with soap request sending to server.   i have attached the code.  Please help me in this

```
 BOOL status;

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;

    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    urlString = @"hoegamestg.hogaming.info";

    // urlString = @"247liveagent.hointeractive.com";



    if (![urlString isEqualToString:@""])

    {
        NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        if (!website)
        {

            NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL", urlString);
            status = NO;


        }

        else

        {
            NSLog(@"URL IS VALID%@",website );



            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) [website host], 5654, &readStream, &writeStream);



            //  CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) urlString, 5654, &readStream, &writeStream);


            //USE TOLL-FREE BRIDGING FOR CONVERTING CORE-FOUNDATION STREAMS TO NSSTREAMS.


            self.inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
            self.outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

            //SET DELEGATES TO STREAMS.

            [self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
            [self.outputStream setDelegate:self];

            //AVOID BLOCKING OPERATIONS BY SCHEDULING THEM ON TO RUN LOOPS.

            [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            //FINALLY OPEN THE STREAMS.

            [self.inputStream open];
            [self.outputStream open];


        }

    }......
```

Delegate method and soap request

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{

    // Start Logging events.
   // NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",eventCode];
   // NSMutableString *subscribeTableString;

    NSData *data;

    NSString *soapMessage = [[NSString alloc]init];



    switch (eventCode) {

        case NSStreamEventNone:
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventNone");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventOpenCompleted");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");

            [self readDataFromStream];

            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:


            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable");


            soapMessage=[soapMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<subscribe channel=\"table-bc7ire5oi4uhetfd\" ><player id=\"%@\" />",socketValue ]];

           // soapMessage=[soapMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<subscribe channel=\"table-bc7ire5oi4uhetfd\" ><player id= \"c2da1a80c52542dd\" />" ]];




            soapMessage =[soapMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<sessionid id=\"%@\"",socketname]];

            soapMessage =[soapMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"></sessionid></subscribe>"]];


            NSLog(@"THE STRING IS : %@", soapMessage);


        data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];


            [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];


            NSLog(@"THE STRING IS : %@", self.outputStream);



            [self setMWriteData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(__bridge const void*)soapMessage length:

                                 [soapMessage length]]];


            [self writeDataToStream];


         //   <subscribe channel="table-l8i2hq4jo2hjj9ca"><player id="b82fe3c52020494b" /><sessionid id="246421321cc873d080b550bcc555de0e9d9d29d8cba6f243ec56d38c5785"></sessionid></subscribe>

            break;


        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:


            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred");
            NSLog(@"THE ERROR IS : %@", [aStream streamError]);

            break;


        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            break;

        default:

            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: You can try using this alternative called SocketRocket. It worked well for me.
https://github.com/square/SocketRocket

Comment: thanks for reply. I have tried socket rocket but i didn't get a response . I am struggling with how to send soap request to the server......

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, SOAP is based on the HTTP protocol, so you cannot use raw sockets for that.  You can refer to this question if you do need SOAP: [how to send/recieve soap object with objective c for ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433896/how-to-send-recieve-soap-object-with-objective-c-for-ipad)

However, if you meant simply sending XML over raw sockets, then you'll need to tell the receiver when to stop reading.

HTTP's way of ending streams is adding `\r\n\r\n` to the end of the string, so you can use that.

Another way is sending a 4 byte header with the amount of bytes to be sent, so add this (untested):

```
int s = [data length];
NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&s length:4];
[self.outputStream write:[size bytes] maxLength:[size length]];
```

before this

```
[self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

The server needs to be aware of this and treat every first 4 bytes as the header, and then reading the amount of bytes mentioned in the header.

I think it would be easier to use HTTP's method with the server stopping its reading when it encounters `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Now i got following response from server

Comment: <3c737562 73637269 62652063 68616e6e 656c3d22 7461626c 652d6263 37697265 356f6934 75686574 6664223e 3c706c61 79657220 69643d22 30656533 32666137 30373365 34346462 22202f3e 3c736573 73696f6e 69642069 643d2264 62346166 38333836 66313361 30383334 34353764 65393633 64643135 63646436 32626662 63393261 63343530 61323662 34336531 65656636 61623932 38633222 3e3c2f73 65737369 6f6e6964 3e3c2f73 75627363 72696265 3e>